# Trying to use SDR as TV tuner, works fine until I use it as an SDR, then needs to reboot

Tags: kernel, tv, tv-tuner

I've made sure the SDR-specific kernel module (`rtl2832`) is unloaded, and that `dvb_usb_rtl28xxu`, `dvb_usb_v2`, `rtl2832`, and `dvb_core` are all loaded. There are no errors trying to open or scan for TV signals, it just does not load anything in VLC and fails to find anything with `w_scan`. It is still able to scan successfully, just without any success. Going back into Gqrx (SDR software) shows that the TV signal is still there, although I am unable to test its validity as I do not know how to do anything with a signal that big in Gqrx. I have tried unplugging and plugging back in, unloading and reloading those kernel modules, and only rebooting works.

Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: Please edit your question and provide the version of Ubuntu you are using.

Comment: @OrganicMarble alright, done